# How to create a new firebase project using reset firebase api

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, postman

i am trying to create a new project in firebase console useing firebse rest api in postman.

i am geting error status of 400 and message like "Request contains an invalid argument".

Please let me know how to do the api call.

here is my screenshort
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The REST API you're using can't create new projects.  It can only modify existing projects.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project):

> Note: If you don't already have an existing Google Cloud project, you can create one using the [projects.create](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method in the [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects) or by using the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

You'll have to use the linked Google Cloud API to create a project, then add Firebase to it using Firebase's own REST API.

You should also read all of the documentation very carefully, as there are a lot of prerequisites for using the API that it looks like you haven't done yet.  The APIs all require authentication using a service account, as well as the enablement of various APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Do you have any idea how I can create a new Firebase project using rest API?

Comment: I already gave you links to the documentation for the APIs for creating and managing projects.  If you're having problems working with those, please post separately with your code and debugging details.

Comment: Yes, I get that but will this 'https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create' method give me a new Firebase project in the same account? 

i think this method create some thing in GCP.

Comment: No, you have to create a GCP project first, then add Firebase to that project with another call.  Firebase projects are just GCP projects with certain APIs enabled.